# Find and replace part of a property value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I need to search for a keyword over an array of objects and replace all instances of it.

For example, I have the following array:

```
const test = [
  {
    marketType: 90,
    displayName: "FT Total Match {scoreType} Over / Under 0.75 Remove",
},
{
    marketType: 90,
    displayName: "FT Total Match {scoreType} Over / Under 1 Remove",
},
]
```

I want to find and replace all `{scoreType}` with `goals` in the array above.

So far I have tried converting the array to a string, running a replace on it, and converting it back to an array. But when I console log the result, I still see `{scoreType}` and no errors.

```
console.log('result: ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test).replace('{scoreType}', 'goals')));
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do something like this perhaps:

```js
const test = [
  {
    marketType: 90,
    displayName: "FT Total Match {scoreType} Over / Under 0.75 Remove",
},
{
    marketType: 90,
    displayName: "FT Total Match {scoreType} Over / Under 1 Remove",
},
]

newTest = test.map(obj => ({...obj, displayName: obj.displayName.replace('{scoreType}', 'goals')}))
console.log(newTest);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try with `map`:

```
const result = test.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  displayName: item.displayName.replace('{scoreType}', 'goals'),
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting an object to string and then working on it is a very vague approach and may lead to undesired bugs.

You may loop over the array using `Array#forEach`, and replace the text of `displayName` by using a regular expression, generated out of the source string.

```js
const test = [{
    marketType: 90,
    displayName: "FT Total Match {scoreType} Over / Under 0.75 Remove",
  },
  {
    marketType: 90,
    displayName: "FT Total Match {scoreType} Over / Under 1 Remove",
  },
];

const search = 'scoreType';
const replacement = 'goal';

test.forEach(item => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`\{${search}\}`, 'g')
  item.displayName = item.displayName.replace(regex, replacement);
});

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate and replace displayName like this.

```
var updatedTest = test.map(obj => ({...obj, displayName: obj.displayName.replace('{scoreType}', 'goals')}));
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your original code, you would have to use a *global* regular expression `replace`:

```js
const test = [
  {
    marketType: 90,
    displayName: "FT Total Match {scoreType} Over / Under 0.75 Remove",
},
{
    marketType: 90,
    displayName: "FT Total Match {scoreType} Over / Under 1 Remove",
},
]

console.log('result: ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test).replace(/{scoreType}/g, 'goals')));
```