# How can I remove some texts from a string which is inside of an object and object is in the array?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove `description:("Auto-generated by YouTube.")` from `title`?

```
[
  {
    title: 'DÁKITI description:("Auto-generated by YouTube.")',
    author: 'Bad Bunny',
    duration: 205090
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hope this helps.. https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/VwmWgLM

Comment: @adiga I think this question involes more than just *remove text from a string* It is also about iterating an array and writing an object property

Comment: @Aalexander there are hundreds of duplicates on how to iterate over arrays and manipulate a property. And, there are plenty of questions about iterating and replacing particular property like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667175/find-and-replace-part-of-a-property-value-in-an-array-of-objects

Comment: @adiga yes but your original duplicate wasn't appropriate for this question. *How to remove text from a string? (12 answers)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) array method, i guess you have other elements in the array  with the same substring, then for each one use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) string method:

```js
let data = [
  {
    title: 'DÁKITI description:("Auto-generated by YouTube.")',
    author: 'Bad Bunny',
    duration: 205090
  }
]

let result = data.map(e => ({...e,title:e.title.replace('description:("Auto-generated by YouTube.")','').trim()}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with multiple objects with the auto generated description you can use `forEach` and update the title attribute of each element.

Why *forEach* is a better choice than *map*

forEach will **not** create a new array like **map** will do, it will simply update your existing array.

```
data.forEach(e => {
    e.title = e.title.replace('description:("Auto-generated by YouTube.")', '');
  })
```

```js
let data = [{
  title: 'DÁKITI description:("Auto-generated by YouTube.")',
  author: 'Bad Bunny',
  duration: 205090
}]

data.forEach(e => {
  e.title = e.title.replace('description:("Auto-generated by YouTube.")', '');
})

console.log(data)
```